# Can "неужели" be used in a sentence that isn’t a question?

Tags: значения

I’m translating an audio in Russian, where the speaker says, “поэтому я так счастлива что ... неужели ура!” i might be hearing the speaker incorrectly, but if not, I was wondering what неужели meant in this context.

Answer (score 1):

It would have been nice to have at least the first part of the sentence as some context, but even considering the given part we can tell that the result was long hoped for and the speaker did some great job, so this can be interpreted as "it happened to be successful at last" with some surprise.

поэтому я так счастлива что ... неужели ура!(**неужели наконец получилось**)